# Promise success not working

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, promise

I am new to angular and been trying some stuff for fun to get acquainted. I can't seem to get promise to work. The update action works fine. I don't get anything printed in console.

```
app.factory "Profile", [ 
    "$resource"
    "$q"
    ($resource, $q) ->
        Profile = ->
            @service = $resource("/users/profiles/:id.json", {id: @id}, 'update': {method: 'PATCH', params: {id: '@id'}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
            return
        Profile::show = (userId) ->
            @service.get(id: userId)
        Profile::update = (updatedProfileObject) ->
            deferred = $q.defer()
            @service.update(id: updatedProfileObject.id, profile: updatedProfileObject).success = (response) ->
                deferred.resolve
                    message: "great success borat"
                return
            deferred.promise
        return new Profile
]


app.controller "MainCtrl", [
    "$scope"
    "$routeParams"
    "Profile"
    "$route"
    "$rootScope"
    "$q"
    ($scope,$routeParams,Profile,$route,$rootScope,$q) -> 
        $rootScope.$on "$routeChangeSuccess", ->
            $scope.profile = Profile.show($routeParams.id)
            return
        $scope.range = (min, max, step) ->
        step = (if (step is `undefined`) then 1 else step)
        input = []
        i = min
        while i <= max
            input.push i
            i += step
        input
        $scope.update = ->
            promise = Profile.update($scope.profile)
            promise.then = (response) ->
                console.log(response.message)
]
```

Updated code to fix syntax for controller update method and factory update method and its still now working.

Updated code:

```
app.factory "Profile", [ 
    "$resource"
    "$q"
    ($resource, $q) ->
        Profile = ->
            @service = $resource("/users/profiles/:id.json", {id: @id}, 'update': {method: 'PATCH', params: {id: '@id'}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
            return
        Profile::show = (userId) ->
            @service.get(id: userId)
        Profile::update = (updatedProfileObject) ->
            deferred = $q.defer()
            @service.update(id: updatedProfileObject.id, profile: updatedProfileObject).$promise.then (value) ->
                deferred.resolve();
            deferred.promise
        return new Profile
]


app.controller "MainCtrl", [
    "$scope"
    "$routeParams"
    "Profile"
    "$route"
    "$rootScope"
    "$q"
    ($scope,$routeParams,Profile,$route,$rootScope,$q) -> 
        $rootScope.$on "$routeChangeSuccess", ->
            $scope.profile = Profile.show($routeParams.id)
            return
        $scope.range = (min, max, step) ->
        step = (if (step is `undefined`) then 1 else step)
        input = []
        i = min
        while i <= max
            input.push i
            i += step
        input
        $scope.update = ->
            Profile.update($scope.profile).then (value) -> 
                console.log("lol")
```

Comment: `defer.resolve` takes a parameter which should be the resolved data.

Comment: I put the data within the resolve and still having the same issue

Comment: did it work at last ?

Answer (score 0):

remove the "=" sign at the line before the last one, then takes a callback

```
promise.then (response) ->
                console.log(response.message)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding again. I tried that and now its saying success is not a function :(

Comment: ... mmh $resource doesn't return a promise. i guess you need to access it using $promise (@service.update(..).$promise.then -> ...)

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing `]` on your controller definition.